# Could not resolve project :react-native-maps

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm getting this error when trying build gradle :

**Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :react-native-maps.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > No matching configuration of project :react-native-maps was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.2.1' but:
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.**

Knowing that I have added this in build.gradle:app:

````
implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'```
````

Answer (score 0):

Go to your settings.gradle file and remove all lines referencing react-native-maps (refer to conversation in link)
https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4224